# why there are different datarates for each WLAN apmmendment?

Tags: wifi

Why there are different data rates in each WLAN protocol. 
Ex: 802.11 supports 1 and 2 Mbps, 
    802.11a can support 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 54
    802.11b can support 1, 2, 5.5, 11 
    etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**802.11 and 802.11b**:

Each data bits is converted into multiple bits of information for protection against errors due to noise or interference. Each of the new coded bits is called a chip. The different data rates has different chipping methods.

For example:

- 1 and 2 Mbps using the Barker code.
- 5.5 and 11 Mbps using Complementary Code Keying (CCK)

Both run at 11 Mchips/s.

Barker code has 11 chip code per symbol, CCK has 8 chip code per symbol =>
Symbol rate for Barker code 11000000/11 = 1 Msps, for CCK 1.375 Msps.

For Barker code:

- DBPSK can modulate 1 bit of data => 1 bit * 1 Msps = 1 Mbps
- DQPSK can modulate data bits in pairs => 2 bits * 1Msps = 2 Mbps

For CCK:

- 4 bits * 1.375 Msps = 5.5 Mbps
- 8 bits * 1.375 Msps = 11 Mbps

**802.11g(802.11a):**

This standart use OFDM modulation scheme. Look at modulation types:

- BPSK (1 bit per symbol) => max rate is 12Mbps
- QPSK (2 bits per symbol) => max rate is 24 Mbps
- 16-QAM (4 bits per symbol) => max rate is 48 Mbps
- 64-QAM (6 bits per symbol) => max rate is 72 Mbps

This types use [code rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_rate) for error correction:

- BPSK 1/2 => 6 Mbps
- BPSK 3/4 => 9 Mbps
- QPSK 1/2 => 12 Mbps

and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. May i know the source of the above information? And i have one more question on top of this, in 11g (11a) we have BPSK, QPSK, 16-QAM, 64-QAM with different data rates, why can't we use one and only the higher data rate i.e., in this case 64-QAM => 72 Mbps. I am asking this question in the perspective of distance between STA and AP. Is there a situation like, if the distance between the STA and AP changes, the data rates also changes?

Comment: You can read about this in CCNA Wireless Official Cert Guide.
The data rate is selected depending on the noise and signal strength. Under more favorable conditions, less robust coding options may be selected that have the advantage of better transfer speeds for the data at the expense of less error recovery protection.